# I am trying to read in .properties files with Chinese characters encoded in utf-8

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, utf-8, character-encoding

I am trying to read .properties files with having Chinese characters. when I read the them using keys they are printing like ??????. I am writing JSF application. Where I need to do translation for this application in chinese. On UI in JSF it is showing all characters correctly as it should be. But in my java code it is showing like ?????. I donot why it is. I also tried "手提電話" and also tried "\u88dc\u7fd2\u500b\u6848" and tried to print them on console with main function, it is printing correctly in chinese lang chars. my properties file having encoding utf-8.

To clarify your confusion about it, I am able to display them console in chinese like

```
 String str="Алексей";
    String str="\u88dc\u7fd2\u500b\u6848";
    System.out.println("direct output: "+str);
```

working fine in psvm. but after reading using properties file is shows ???.e
Hope it is clear now.
Also My database is receiving the ?? in place for actual chinese charactersets.

Please help. any other clarification required then please confirm so I can update my lines over here.

Here is my code for reading the properties file which returns the bundle of relevant locale.

```
 FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                    bundle = context.getApplication().getResourceBundle(context, "hardvalue");
```

after this I am going to call this to access the value:

```
bundle.getString("tutorsearch.header"); // results in ?????
```

Any other code you need then please confirm.

Comment: It looks like you're asking two unrelated questions here? You should limit each post to one question.

Comment: Regarding your properties question, the question title asks how to read a properties file containing chinese. But the actual question seems to say you're reading them in okay; you're just having trouble displaying them? Please edit your question to describe your actual problem in detail, and include your source code which is relevant to the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple question marks *usually* comes from

- you had utf8-encoded data (good)
- `SET NAMES latin1` was in effect (default, but wrong)
- the column was declared `CHARACTER SET latin1` (default, but wrong)

For Chinese (or Emoji), you need to use MySQL's `utf8mb4`.

The cure (for future `INSERTs`):

- utf8-encoded data (good)
- `mysqli_set_charset('utf8mb4')` (or whatever your client needs for establishing the `CHARACTER SET`)
- check that the column(s) and/or table default are `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`
- If you are displaying on a web page, `<meta...charset=utf-8>` should be near the top.  (Note different spelling.)

Comment: @SET NAMES latin1: I didn't get what you are talking about. Actually I want to know the how to change it and what it should be. I am using this in hibernate     <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf-8</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf-8</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>. Does it require to change some thing here about database. Beside this I am not able to get what is the issue of question mark. Can you please help. If you need to check the code block then I agree to edit my question with code.thanks

Comment: Well, since I don't know Hibernate, I can't say.  But `hibernate.connection...`, etc certainly sounds like the right things to set.  The various encodings (latin1, utf8, etc) have different ways to represent characters.  When an unrecognizable encoding is handed off, it turns into '?' or is truncated.

Comment: utf8mb4 bytes for Chinese characters, "converted" to latin1, become '???' because there is no representation for them.  My overly long discussion of the problems is [here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll).

Comment: Let's check tings from a different angle...  `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...` to fetch the hex of something that has gone wrong.  This will let us see if the text was _stored_ correctly or not.  Then we know whether to focus on 'storing' or on 'fetching'.

Comment: I am very confused with this question mark in my java code. If I am trying to insert chinese characters into database, it is working. But from JSF to my JAVA code, when some one select any option from multiple then its giving ?. Also I am trying to load properties bundle in my jsf application then its resulting in ?. This is my actual Issue.

Comment: You are `INSERTing` Chinese (or any non-western-Europe text).  You said `SET NAMES utf8` to declare that the client bytes are utf8-encoded.  But the columns are declared `CHARSET latin1`.  Since there is no way to convert Chinese characters into latin1, you get a '?' stored in the table.

Answer (score 0):

adding below tagging have resolved my issue.

```
<properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
```

Thanks to All